# Which No Sql database to use

Tags: database, database-design

I am looking for a non-SQL database. 
My requirements are as follow:

- Should be able to store >10 billion records
- Should consume only 1 gb of memory atmost.
- User request should take less than 10 ms. (including processing time)

Java based would be great.(i need to access it from java and also if anytime I need to modify the database code )

The database will hold e-commerce search records like number of searches ,sales , product bucket,product filters...and many more...the database now is a flat file and I show now some specific data to users.The data to be show I configure prior and then according to that configuration users can send http request to view data. I want to make things more dynamic and people can view data without prior configuration....

In other words I want to built a fast analyzer which can show users what the user request for.

Comment: The performance figures will be dependent on how you implement your database, the environment it runs in, etc. Why do you want to use a non-SQL database? Do you still want a relational database, or an OO database, or an XML database, or a flat-file database? Do you want a database implemented in Java (which is what you've asked), or a database accessible using Java? You'll need to explain what you want in a lot more detail.

Comment: Which ones are object oriented database?? and which ones are xml database..?

Comment: An XML database is an XML file which you are using to store data. There are a number of different object-oriented databases. Please explain what you are hoping to achieve, and why a SQL database will not be suitable.

Comment: ahh..because i will be having tables with too many columns only a few of which are actually used by any particular row...and many more reason...

Comment: @Saurabh, a normalised SQL schema is designed to deal with the problem of "too many columns..."

Comment: please name some xml database or oops database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to find names of non-relational databases is the NoSQL site.  Their home page has a pretty comprehensive list, split onto various categories - Wide Column Store, Key-value Pair, Object, XML, etc.  [Find out more](http://nosql-database.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really give enough information about your requirements. But it sounds like [kdb+](http://kx.com/kdb+.php) meets all of the requirements that you've stated. But only if you want to get to grips with the rather exotic (and very powerful) [Q language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205/whats-your-favourite-programming-language-and-its-killer-feature/2257828#2257828).